Sending a specific ETH balance - FiFo
I'd like to send a specific balance of ETH from one address using Metmask. Does anyone know how to identify specific tokens and then execute a transaction using only these tokens while all other tokens in the address will not be touched.
Thanks

Just click the send button, enter the address, and confirm. No other token would be touched.

Thanks for your reply. please let me clarify...
Let's say I have an address with a total balance of  1 ETH. That 1 ETH was accumulated in the address by 10 transactions of 0.1 ETH each over a longer period of time. Now I'd like to send the first 0.1 ETH out and make sure that no other of the remaining 0.9 ETH (excluding the obvious gas fees) is part of the transaction. How do I do that? Thanks
